# Manhwa about a boy who knows martial arts, but goes to the past and applies to be a magician

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic, manga, martial-arts

The manhwa is new but is about a boy who knows martial arts, but in the time period he lives in, magicians are better. He went to a dungeon and found like a eye, and then he fought a person in a dungeon, and then he went to the past and applied to be magician. Also, another thing I remember is that he took like a test to see how much magician class was compatible with him, and it was 93 or 97.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You said this was a manhwa, so was this in full colour? Also, do you recall if the main character had short hair or long hair, and what colour his hair was?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

*I Obtained a Mythic Item*, aka *[Mythic Item Obtained](https://myanimelist.net/manga/150561/Mythic_Item_Obtained)* by Jung SeonYul.

> In a world where technology and magic are almost indistinguishable from one another, monsters and creatures of myth and legend reign terror upon mankind. In humanity's darkest moment, individuals with special god-like powers emerge to save the day. They are—the Awakened. Meet Jaehyeon, a feeble Awakened human Raider, who struggles to make ends meet until one day a series of confounding events allow him to claim a powerful item that will change the course of history forever...

Comment: You should describe this and explain how it matches.

Comment: I've added a quick copy-and-paste summary. In the webnovel, he does find the Eye of Odin in the 0th chapter. Four chapters into the webcomic, I haven't seen it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I read the first 5 chapters, and this is definitely the correct answer.  All the details of the question are correct, even down to his 97% affinity score for magic.