# Modern hunting and reincarnation

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manhwa is new but is about a boy who knows martial arts, but in the time period he lives in, magicians are better. He went to a dungeon and found like a eye, and then he fought a person in a dungeon, and then he went to the past and applied to be magician. Also, another thing I remember is that he took like a test to see how much magician class was compatible with him, and it was 93 or 97.

Comment: This is a word-for-word duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264725