# Manhwa about a guy who became a warrior, then died and became a mage in his next life

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, reincarnation

It's a leveling manhwa set in modern times, where the main character chose to be a warrior but had no talent in it. He then died and became a mage instead, because he had a high aptitude in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be [*I Obtained a Mythic Item*](https://asura.gg/manga/i-obtained-a-mythic-item/). The blurb reads:

> Yggdrasil, the World Tree of Norse Mythology, suddenly appeared on Earth. And with it came demonic creatures that ravaged entire cities.
>
> Although not all hope is lost, due to the System that a few special humans had gained.
>
> In this new world where only the strong survived, Min JaeHyun scrapes by regretting the wrong choices he’d made in the past… when one day, he gains the only Mythic item in the world.
>
> How will this item help him? And can he change his wretched fate?

Min has a 97% magic aptitude, but opted to study martial arts instead (even though his aptitude was only 34%) because he thought that magic users were looked down on.  But as a 27-year-old D-rank martial arts specialist, he realizes that they are only disposable shields for magic users, especially at D-rank.

Then a dungeon crawl goes wrong and, just before dying, he gains a mythic item, "Odin's Lost Eye."  His original plan is to sell it, but he is betrayed and attacked, so he equips the eye.

When he dies he is sent back 11 years to when he first chose to study martial arts, and, knowing how that turns out, instead chooses magic.  But now not only does he have his huge aptitude (one of the best ever), he has a mythic item that allows him to unwind other people's spells and copy them.

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264725/manhwa-about-a-boy-who-knows-martial-arts-but-goes-to-the-past-and-applies-to-b/269148#269148 (no Duplicate without acceptance, but linking this in the system).